# Exit application on back key press

Tags: windows-phone-7

I navigate through different pages in my application. At some time I come to my home page and by pressing the back button I want to exit my application while I am at homepage but each time I press the back button it goes to the previous page. I succeed to cancel the navigation overriding the backkeypress property of the application.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
         e.cancel = true;
   }
```

Is there any similar way to exit the application ?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875875/exit-application-on-back-button-on-wp7

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK - there is no API to exit your app. It is supposed to only be done by the user and rightly so, since an app exiting in a non-standard way would confuse a user. I think the only way to exit your app is to get an unhandled exception, but if you make that into a feature - your app might not pass certification.

Comment: I did not any specific solution to the problem. So I created an random exception on the backkey press and exited my application.

If there's any alternate answer then please specify.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your application **will not** pass marketplace certification if the application exits unexpected (such as with a exception!)

Comment: Let me repeat that - you can work around it, but unless the tests do not detect it - your app will fail certification if you exit the application programmatically. If you want to exit the app when you are in the home page - make it so that your home page is the first page when you start the application. There should be no other way reach your home page later than having the user go back through the back stack using the back button and there should be no button in your application to jump through the back stack. If you really have to - look for the non-linear navigation sample to go back home.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove  e.cancel = true; and try again

Answer (score -1):

```
        this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        e.Cancel = false;
```

Comment: Please can you add some explanation of your code to your post.